# Dialog Activity - Custom Theme

Tags: android, xamarin

I have been trying to implement a custom theme on my activity dialog, The goal is to achieve the following

[image]

I am showing the `Progressbar` for 15 seconds before closing the activity and my activity dialog looks like the following

[image]

Although it's doing what it is supposed to do, I am still not getting the following results

> **1.** The background is "**Transparent**" where I want it to be completely transparent like the first screenshot
>
> **2.** I put the activity as `ExcludeFromRecents = true` but it still shows in the **recent applications** list during those 15 seconds

Now to the code,

> My Dialog Layout is the following  - `DialogActivityLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center" 
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressRecicer"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
         android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

> My Dialog Theme style is the following in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppCompatDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>   
  </style>
```

> My Activity code is the following

```
[Activity(Label = "Dialog Activity", MainLauncher = false, Theme = "@style/AppCompatDialogTheme", ExcludeFromRecents = true)]
```

Where my Activity `OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method is the following

```
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DialogActivityLayout);
Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
this.SetFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppCompatDialogTheme);
Toast.MakeText(this, "Dialog Activity Opened", ToastLength.Long).Show();
Handler h = new Handler();
Action myAction = () =>
{
  Finish();
};
h.PostDelayed(myAction, 15000);
```

any help to achieve these two goals is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the dim amount you have to use this :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = progressDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.dimAmount = 0.5f; //Ranges from 0 to 1.
progressDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
progressDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

So you just have to set it to 0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your direction, although I didn't use your code although it gave me the clear idea of what I was looking for, so I added the following in my `styles.xml` for  my custom dialog `<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>` I- I will make this as an answer and create a new question for the second part. cheers